# What is the correct way to find the differences between 2 relational tables?

Tags: database, sql

Typically the solution for comparing if 2 relational db tables (I am using AWS Athena) are equal is to do full outer join on all the columns but adding an extra column to each dataset that acts as a marker.

```
select *
from 
(
    (select *, 't1' as t1 from table1 where ...) t1
    full outer join
    (select *, 't2' as t2 from table2 where ...) t2
    on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 and ...
)
where t1 is null or t2 is null
```

This gives you the differing rows. But I want to go a step further and find on which columns the row differ.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure how to model this, even in a script. If a join failed, that means that the rows where t2 is null (i.e rows in t1 not in t2) and rows where t1 is null (i.e rows in t2 not in t1) could differ on any of the columns or even just not be present in the other table at all. How would I know what 2 rows to compare to find the differences?

I'd appreciate some help modeling the algorithm here. The above query will give me what rows do not have a full match in the other table. But for each row where there's a mismatch, how do I find where the mismatch occurred?

1 way I can think of doing this is once I have the result set of differing rows, I will join the t1 diffs with the t2 diffs on each column (i.e "join on col a", then "join on col a and col b", then "join on col a and col b and col c"), and that will tell me the differences, but I'm sure there are edge cases + that is a lot of queries to do for wide tables.

Another way I can think of is grouping. I would group on all the columns, which gives me a list of groups, and then I order by all the columns. Similar columns would thus show up next to each other, but I don't know if this is fool-proof because what if the columns match on col a, b, d but not col c, and I order by a, b, c, d?

Reminder that this is in AWS Athena, so certain SQL statements are not available.

Comment: For the general case, this is going to be a factorially hard combinatorics problem. What do you think are the "differences" between the two sets `{(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)}` and `{(1, 5, 9), (4, 8, 3), (7, 2, 6)}`?

Comment: @PhilipKendall yeah I agree, to me it seems like a tuple similarity problem, or I define subsets of dimensions and join on each of those subsets making this is a 2^n problem. For your example, I guess I would say they differ on col 2 and col 3 (because col 1 of 1,4,7 is the same).

Comment: But column 2 is also `{2, 5, 8}` and column 3 is `{3, 6, 9}` (yes, this was obviously deliberate). What makes you say column 1 is more important than column 2 or 3? Ordering?

Comment: The set of values in each column is the same, but when you take a subset of the columns, the sets differ. Like if we know that column 1 matches completely, then we would join on column 1, and we would see differing values for col 2 and col 3 coming from the different sets, 2 vs 5 and 3 vs 9 for for col 1 = 1 for example. However I recognize we don't know in advance that col 1 is the same.

Comment: So what would you say are the differences between `{(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)}` and `{(7, 2, 6), (1, 5, 9), (4, 8, 3)}`? Unless you have a well defined sort key, you can't assume the ordering of very much at all in SQL.

Comment: Visually, I'd say the difference is col 1 and col 3 because col 2 matches completely. But you're right, I am assuming the sort key is 2 in this example based on the fact in advance. i would not know the sort key in advance. I assumed there might be some vector similarity solution to this but maybe not.

Answer (score 3):

Tables we care about have a Primary Key.
Always.

Assume both tables have similar PK.
JOIN on that, with filtering WHERE conjunction to pick out mismatched rows.
Store them in a temp table and solve that as a separate problem.

---

Compute MD5 or SHA3 hash of all rows during the JOIN on PK.
Use that instead of a multi column conjunct.
Cache such hashes if you frequently re-compare tables.

---

Add an “updated” timestamp column, indexed, to tables you frequently re-compare.
Then an index scan of the < 1% of rows that recently changed
will quickly reveal the diffs, while ignoring the vast number
of boring rows that will prove uninformative.

---

Database tables without PK are the moral equivalent of text files. So export to .CSV format, perhaps with first column being the row-wise hash, run it through /usr/bin/sort, and use `diff -u` to review the wreckage.

Answer (score 0):

> This gives you the differing rows. But I want to go a step further and
> find on which columns the row differ.

As you point out this is really giving you rows from t1 which have no match in t2 and vice versa. Subtly different from "differing rows"

When you take it a step further and want to know on which cols they differ, well row 1 in t1 is obviously going to be different from all but one row in t2. Presumably you don't actually want all the data squared?

If you are using Athena I assume you have a machine learning problem? It would seem to me what you really want to do is group similar rows to find categories.

This can be done by turning each columns value into an integer and plotting the rows as a vector in n dimensional space. You can then group by proximity. You will be able to see clusters of rows which are extremely different from other clusters, groups where everything is the same except a couple of fields etc etc. Various models can be used to extract the categories.

Once you have categories of rows you can start asking meaningful questions about differences, by comparing individual rows against the set as a whole and categories within the set.

- Which column has the most variation?
- Is this row "normal"?
- How many rows fall outside the main groups?